# Adding annotations to tradingview / lightweight-charts

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I would like to add annotations(you could say it's a text note) to the tradingview as shown in the following picture.

[image]

I tried to use series marker.
but, it bothers me that I can't add & design a box that wraps around text.

And I don't want to use Technical Analysis Charts because I only need that function(annotations). I don't even have a completed homepage to fill out the application form.

Is there a way to add annotations to the tradingview(lightweight-charts)?

Help me, brothers

/## https://www.tradingview.com/

Answer (score 2):

Im afraid it's not possible right now. `lightweight-charts` doesn't support drawings at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly with `lightweight-charts` but thoese kind of "expansions" should be relatively easy to do.

What you could do is add an overlay on top of the chart.

An easy way would be to create a `<div>` and just add it on top of the chart and customize it as you want with some CSS.